# Cannot use webrtc.io package; JavaScript error on browser

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, video-streaming, webrtc

I have just started working with [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). I want to use WebRTC with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/).

Currently I have tried [webrtc.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) package. When I write a basic code for using WebRTC, I get the following JavaScript error.

Error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error 
rtc._socket.onopen
```

Error Location:

```
webrtc.io.js:65
```

Here is my code.

CLIENT CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 getUserMedia</title>
    <script src="socket.io.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="webrtc.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script>

        rtc.connect('ws://abc.in:8001');

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="webcam" width="500" autoplay></video>
</body>

</html>
```

SERVER CODE :

```
var webRTC = require('/usr/local/node_modules/webrtc.io').listen( 8001 );

console.log( "Server Listening" );

webRTC.on( "connection", function() {

console.log( "Hi" ); // This gets executed successfully.
});
```

**Q1.** 
Since "Hi" does get printed successfully, I don't know if JS error is actually making a difference or no. Help me resolve this JS error issue.
Issue also [reported here.](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io/issues/41)

**Q2.** 
Hitting http://abc.in:8001/ through browser prints "Not implemented". Is that an issue?

**Q3.** 
I wish to stream the audio+video from a mic and webcam to the server.

I understand that I need to create a peer to peer connection to achieve streaming of audio+video to server. Browser should act as one peer and the server would act as the second peer.

How do I send the WebRTC stream to the server? Lack of documentation of the [webrtc.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) package isn't helping me either.

Please help

EDIT : Browser used is the latest Google Chrome, Version 31.0.1650.57 m

Comment: Can you inlcude the full client code?

Comment: Edited the question to include the full client code! Won't help though, there is only one line of Javascript present.

Comment: Have you tried to implement it just the way it's shown in the official example https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io#example-code ?

Comment: Yes, the code I have mentioned here is the same. Isn't it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are some obivous differences in the Client-side code.

Comment: Yes, but that code is not important code. BTW, I have tried with that code too. It does not make any difference. Do u have any idea about the Q2 or Q3 that I have mentioned?

Comment: Have you checked your Browser Flags: https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io#browser-support

Comment: The first two were disabled, I enabled them. But, still getting the error. :( The 3rd option is not available. :( :(

Comment: What I feel is that the first 2 flags are not mandatory to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded simplest webRTC code at

http://github.com/aungthuya-jse/simplest-webRTC/tree/master

You need to add the node_modules to under of project folder by  installing

npm install express

and

npm install webrtc.io

after installation you will see /project-folder/node_modules/express folder and webrtc.io folder

Comment: I don't think 'room name' is important! Is it? If no, then why is the [most simple example listed here](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) not running.! :(

Comment: room name is important in web rtc, because user can share video or file another user in the same room only. I have simplest code for webrtc.io. I'll share to you. please wait a minutes.

Comment: I uploaded simplest webRTC code at https://github.com/aungthuya-jse/simplest-webRTC/tree/master You need to add the node_modules\....